# Lua + C/C++/C# / Как вывести сообщение?

Tags: c#, c++, c, lua

Слышал что луа взаимодействует с языками Си(значит плюсы и шарп тоже сюда входят). Как вывести сообщение в консоль на этих трёх языках так, чтобы я мог это запустить в файле .lua. С гугла код(немного изменённый) не подходит: `#include <iostream>`
`int main() {std::cout << "Thanks for viewing my code!"; return 0;}`

Изменён на:
`#include <iostream>`
`function main() std::cout << "Thanks for viewing my code!"; return 0; end`

Comment: chatGPT сказал мне следующее: `cуществуют несколько библиотек, которые предоставляют поддержку C++ в Lua, например, LuaBridge и LuaJIT FFI.`

Comment: не понятно что вы хотите.  Lua должна выполнить строку `Thanks for viewing my code!` как будто это Lua-программа?

Comment: Да, хочу выполнить код на языке Си или С++, запустив его в файле Lua

Comment: Подготовьте файл и через `os.execute` вызовите `tcc` с параметрами